# Explicity mapping between ActionScript and Java objects for the BlazeDS Messaging Service

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

The BlazeDS documentation shows how to explicitly map between ActionScript and Java objects. For example, this works fine for RPC services, e.g.

```
import flash.utils.IExternalizable;
import flash.utils.IDataInput;
import flash.utils.IDataOutput;

[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="javaclass.User")]
public class User implements IExternalizable {

    public var id : String;
    public var secret : String;

    public function User() {
    }

    public function readExternal(input : IDataInput) : void {
        id = input.readObject() as String;
    }

    public function writeExternal(output : IDataOutput) : void {
        output.writeObject(id);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class User implements Externalizable {

    protected String id;
    protected String secret;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        id = (String) in.readObject();
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(id);
    }
}
```

If I called an RPC service that returns a `User`, the `secret` is not sent over the wire.

Is it also possible to do this for the messaging service? That is, if I create a custom messaging adapter and use the function below, can I also prevent `secret` from being sent?

```
MessageBroker messageBroker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);
AsyncMessage message = new AsyncMessage();
message.setDestination("MyMessagingService");
message.setClientId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
message.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
User user = new User();
user.setId("id");
user.setSecret("secret");
message.setBody(user);
messageBroker.routeMessageToService(message, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with Messaging.  Another option is to use a [BeanProxy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/io/BeanProxy.html) (nice example in this [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/BLZ-305#action_248296)).